# Ubuntu upgrade from 16.04lts to 18.04 no reboot

Tags: boot, upgrade, reboot

[image]

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 and cannot boot in the system. it shows me as per the attached screenshots

Can someone help me on that? Thanks

Comment: Start by typing `fsck -f /` then `exit` and see how far you get. We'll do more if that doesn't fix it for you. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for the above and did what you suggest result is that "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root:UNEXPECTED INCOISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALY. fsck exited with staus code 4 The root file system on/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires manual fsck"

Comment: @haynemma. if of help in the link quoted herein the screenshot. https://we.tl/t-JhANvMAmH0 . Many thanks

Comment: I didn't quite understand your message, and I couldn't look at the link you provided. Please clarify. Please edit your question with the image, or use imgur.com.

Comment: You can try `fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`

Comment: @heynnema, this is what I get in the screen "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root:UNEXPECTED INCOISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALY. fsck exited with staus code 4 The root file system on/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires manual fsck"

Comment: Link for the picture in imgur.com  https://imgur.com/a/9wuIwYr

Comment: the last command you proposed did not work.

Comment: You didn't type the entire command that I gave you. Please retry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the `initramfs` prompt, type:

```
fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```